# Do the vectors with constat dot product with v form a vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

If I have a vector v in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of vectors $ \{\vec x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid \vec {x} \cdot \vec {v}=0 \} $ is a vector space of dimension $n-1.$

I understand it just as a linear equation (restriction) that reduces the dimension, but, is $ \{\vec x\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid \vec {x} \cdot \vec {v}=c\}$ also a vectorspace if $c\neq 0$?

Comment: How much do you know about vector spaces, especially about its definition?

Comment: observe this: if $x,y$ do $x\cdot v=c$ and $y\cdot v=c$ then $(x+y)\cdot v\neq c$

Comment: It isn't a vector subspace, but it is an affine subspace. Specifically, if $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ are in the subset, then $a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}$ is in the subset, provided $a+b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$V= \{\vec x\epsilon \mathbb{R}^n| \vec {x} \cdot \vec {v}=c\}$ is not a vector space.

To define a vector space, we need a non empty set and a field and two operations (one allows us to add two vectors and other allows us to scale a vector).

Here, you consider the vector space operation of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

It is easy to verify that it violates the very first property of vector space (namely closed under addition)

$x, y \in V $

Is this implies $x+y \in V$ ?

$ \vec x \cdot \vec v = c$ and $ \vec y \cdot \vec v = c$

$\vec{ (x+y)} \cdot \vec v = \vec x \cdot \vec v + \vec y \cdot \vec v = 2c$

Hence, if $c\neq 0$ then, $x+y \notin V$

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **no**.

I am not a linear algebra expert, but there are two simple rules of a vector space.

If $\vec{x} \in V$, then $a\vec{x} \in V$ too, for constant $a$.

We already have an issue, because if $a=0$, then the dot product cannot be nonzero.

Comment: This is an okay answer, but:There’s a $c$ in the question, so you shouldn’t use $c$ here for a different purpose.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks for pointing that out.